# How do I convert a binary table in a FITS file to a CSV file in R?

Tags: r, export-to-csv, fits

I have an ML classifier model in R which inputs training set and test set via two large `.csv` files and makes a prediction. However, this model uses pretty large data files (*232 features of 120k+ observations*) and is part of a much bigger pipeline that uses S-lang and C. The testing is done in real-time, so for easy maintainance of the pipeline, all data goes through the different processes as FITS files.

The primary HDU of the input FITS file is an image of zero dimension. The only other extension is a binary table with dimensions 232 cols x 120412 rows.

R doesn't have any tools for manipulating FITS files directly, so I'm trying to use the [FITSio package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FITSio/versions/2.1-0) to read the binary table into a dataframe, which I can then manipulate for the classifier. (I should mention that I'm pretty new to the FITS format)

```
library(FITSio);
filename <- system.file("testdata.fits", package = "FITSio");
zz <- file(description = filename, open = "rb");
header0 <- readFITSheader(zz); # read primary header
header <- readFITSheader(zz); # read extension header
D <- readFITSbintable(zz, header);
close(zz)
```

This throws up an error saying

```
Error in if (nchar(inpString) != 2880) { : argument is of length zero
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there an easier way to import a FITS file and convert it into a CSV file (or just any usable dataframe) in R?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  What do you mean by "R doesn't have any tools for manipulating FITS files directly" if not the FITSio package?

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is.  Is there a traceback showing exactly which line the error originated from?  Otherwise it's not clear what's going on there.  Have you opene that file in other software?   I think you'll find that there are more and better tools for FITS files (and astronomy in general) in Python, but I don't know--maybe the R people are catching up...

Comment: If I had to guess the FITS file is not valid--FITS files are supposed to be a multiple 2880 in length, and it's possible R's FITSio is not robust enough to deal with truncated files.

Comment: @Iguananaut the FITSio package can only read and write into FITS files, but cannot directly explore/plot the data in them or perform any operations. The data first has to be imported, unlike other formats.